# Excel issue with =MID()

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I pull a report, In Column B it has about  125 words, 1100 characters including spaces.

I wrote a =mid() Formula which pulls the server name out of the text without an issue.

```
=MID(B2,FIND("Old Server Name:",B2)+19,FIND("$",B2)-FIND("Old Server Name:",B2)-15)
```

This finds the information, I copied the formula and switched the words Old to New and it Errors #Value! Wrong Data type. The new server data is there and I can use =Right() or =Left()

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("New Server Name:",B2)-15)
```

and

```
=LEFT(D2,FIND("Old Org",D2)-1)
```

Will get to the data but Id rather not have to set 2-3 Cells to trim to the information. Any Ideas? Id post the Data in B2 but it proprietary information.

---

Example B2 content from comments:

```
Name: Fred Flintstone Old Location: Bedrock AK Old Server Name: \\Server\Folder$ Old Org Unit: BED Old Profile Path: \\Server\Folder$\Folder Old Home Directory: \\Server\Folder$ New Location: RockVegas NV New Server Name: \\Server\Folder$ New Org Unit: RVS
```

Comment: Put `=LEN(B2)-FIND("New Server Name:",B2)-15` and `=FIND("Old Org",D2)-1` into separate TEMPORARY cells - there is probably an error in those portions, depending on the content of `D2`

Comment: This works, well "Old Org" is supposed to be "New Org" But I still am trying to figure out why the  =MID() Doesn't work even though its looking in to the same cell for both sets of data.
   Name: Fred Flintstone     Old Location: Bedrock AK     Old Server Name: \\Server\Folder$     Old Org Unit: BED     Old Profile Path: \\Server\Folder$\Folder     Old Home Directory: \\Server\Folder$     New Location: RockVegas NV     New Server Name: \\Server\Folder$     New Org Unit: RVS

Comment: If you select the cell with the formula and hit F2, do you get color markings on `B2`? - If not; verify that that you really should have `,`  and not `;` between formula parameters. Which it should be depends on your locale (Region & Language in the Control panel for Windows), possibly also on Excel/LibreOffice `Use system locale` setting.

Comment: Hmm... I believe that you can `edit` your own questions, so please add bulky text that is related to the question in there. <hr> creates a separator bar, <pre> and </pre> makes the text "and" be formatted as code. If you think you got answer, then make the tick in the upper left of that be green (click on it).

Answer (score 0):

B2:

```
Name: Fred Flintstone Old Location: Bedrock AK Old Server Name: \\Server\Folder$ Old Org Unit: BED Old Profile Path: \\Server\Folder$\Folder Old Home Directory: \\Server\Folder$ New Location: RockVegas NV New Server Name: \\Server\Folder$ New Org Unit: RVS
```

and B3 formula:

```
=RIGHT(B2;LEN(B2)-FIND("New Server Name:";B2)-15)
```

and B3 displays:

```
 \\Server\Folder$ New Org Unit: RVS
```